# How to reduce the masala taste from chicken roast

Tags: chicken, meat, spices, indian-cuisine, roasting

We cooked chicken roast and we cooked it in three batches. this is for a party. 
Good thing- OF the three batches two of them turned out to be pretty good.

Issue- The third one turned out to stand a bit front in masala. Is there a way to reduce the masala taste in this? We mixed all the three batches together (I know we shouldn't have however it was soo late in the night and bad decisions).

The pieces used are legs and thighs.

We are going to make another 3 more batches.

Does anyone have a suggestions?

Wanted to clarify that the spice level is ok. its the whole masala taste which is standing front.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "masala taste"?  As in, the spice flavor from garam masala or another spice blend?  A detailed recipe or method that you're following might also be helpful.

Comment: Try tossing in a few `TBSP` of plain yoghurt, something that should fit the flavour profile. Or, tossing in lime or lemon juice might cut it a bit too (and add a fresh note). Add some chopped cilantro (if you enjoy it) will layer another flavour over what you're suggesting is too much masala goodness.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Olive Oil too in the past with Greek Yogurt with half table spoon honey and lemon and lime to taste. Mix to form paste and apply. Brush light to remove masala coating if you want to or reduce it. Also cool the chicken in fridge so masala is less. Hope I understood your question.